# How to BURP test our outbound message endpoint?

Tags: workflow, security-review, workflowoutboundmessage, burp

We are using some workflows and trigger to send out outbound messages to a listening end-point of ours. We are going into a security review with SF and that requires some testing using BURP. What I have read about BURP is that it is mostly targeted towards testing of web-apps etc., so what exactly do I need to test here. And how can I test my listener endpoint using BURP. Our endpoint does not have any user interface. What do I need to do. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a tool that sends the requests for you.  For example you can use [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) to send REST or SOAP requests.

Follow the directions on the [Cloud Security page](http://security.force.com/security/tools/webapp/burpabout) in the "Effectively Scanning Applications Using Burp" section (copied here with modifications for cURL):

- Turn “Intercept” (Proxy->Intercept) off within Burp. Do not change other default configurations
- Run your commands from cURL.
- Right click on the Target URL (Target->site map) and click on “spider this host”
- Once spidering completes, Right click on the Target URL and click on “actively scan this host”. The scan progress can be monitored under the “Scanner” tab

You can store the body of the request in a file and supply that to the cURL command with the -d argument.  The proxy to the cURL command should be specified as the port the Burp application is running on (likely 127.0.0.1:8080).  For example:

`curl --proxy 127.0.0.1:8080 -k -X POST -d @mySoapBodyFile.txt https://my.endpoint.url.com`

There are also tools like [SOAP UI](http://www.soapui.org/) that you can use to generate the requests instead of cURL.

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with UI. It is especially for WebServices - and I assume your "Listener" is a kind of WebService. There is a Port at an URL where you are listening, right? And it's also hosted somewhere. So it's all about testing your Endpoint - **not your messages.**

Have a look at this
http://security.force.com/security/tools/webapp/burpabout

and that
http://www.fishofprey.com/2013/01/using-burp-suite-to-test-web-service.html

Comment: @Uew The first link is just saying to use it and the features of burp. There is no mention of how to test outbound msgs as that is not a code that is exactly consumed by SF. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: It is not about testing messages. It's about the security of your endpoint. Can your endpoint be hacked and may sensitive data be exposed?

Comment: I recently ran through this and it exposed a few things to do with CSRF and the like, didn't take long to fix. One point to note: when you have zero issues you can't generate a report! I just took a screenshot and that sufficed.